How to exclude a record type from an Apex Trigger
I have inherited some old triggers attached to Opportunities and I would like to stop this particular trigger from running if the record type equals "corporate".
At the moment, the trigger will automatically create a case and assign it to record type "content" when the opportunity is Closed/Won. Can someone help please?
trigger CreateCaseOnOptyCloseWon on Opportunity (before update) {
    List<String> listOpptyIds = new List<String>();
    for(String strOptyId : Trigger.newMap.keyset()) {
        if(Trigger.oldMap.get(strOptyId).StageName != Trigger.newMap.get(strOptyId).StageName &&
            Trigger.newMap.get(strOptyId).StageName.equalsIgnoreCase('Closed Won')) {
            listOpptyIds.add(strOptyId);
        }
    }
    
    if(!listOpptyIds.isEmpty()) {
        if(checkRecursive.runOnce()) {
            CreateCaseOnOptyCloseWonHandler.processOpportunities(listOpptyIds);
        }
    }


Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  We cannot implement your requirements or provide complete designs, but we're happy to help you with issues you encounter as you do your own work.  Please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and where you are stuck.

You can't stop the trigger from firing
but you can add a bit of code to the trigger to prevent the rest of the code in the trigger from executing
trigger CreateCaseOnOptyCloseWon on Opportunity (before update) {
    List<String> listOpptyIds = new List<String>();

    // Records in Trigger Context Variables don't have any data from related records
    //   (i.e. anything where you'd need to use more than one '.' to access it)
    // Instead of using a query (and some supporting code) to get that, we can just
    //   get the Record Type's Id from the SObject type
    Id excludedRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity
    // Be aware that because we're getting data from a map, capitalization matters
        .getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Corporate').getRecordTypeId();

    // Probably makes more sense to just iterate over the records themselves
    //   and access the Id when needed rather than starting with the id and calling
    //   .get() multiple times
    for(Opportunity newOppValue : Trigger.newMap.values()) {
        // Want to skip processing given some criteria?
        // Just use the 'continue' keyword to skip to the next item in the loop
        if(newOppValue.RecordTypeId == excludedRecordTypeId) { 
            continue;
        }

        if(Trigger.oldMap.get(newOppValue.Id).StageName != newOppValue.StageName &&
            newOppValue.StageName.equalsIgnoreCase('Closed Won')) {
            listOpptyIds.add(newOppValue.Id);
        }
    }
    
    if(!listOpptyIds.isEmpty()) {
        if(checkRecursive.runOnce()) {
            CreateCaseOnOptyCloseWonHandler.processOpportunities(listOpptyIds);
        }
    }

The newline between Opportunity and .getRecordTypeInfosByName() was just to help break a long line up for readability (and so I could add a note to that specific part of the line). It could be one line, it could be two, it could be more. Unlike something like python, whitespace is not syntactically significant.
Sometimes, it might make more sense to do an initial pass over the TCV records to build a new collection that just has the stuff that you want to work on.
trigger CreateCaseOnOptyCloseWon on Opportunity (before update) {
    List<String> listOpptyIds = new List<String>();

    // Records in Trigger Context Variables don't have any data from related records
    //   (i.e. anything where you'd need to use more than one '.' to access it)
    // Instead of using a query (and some supporting code) to get that, we can just
    //   get the Record Type's Id from the SObject type
    Id excludedRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity
    // Be aware that because we're getting data from a map, capitalization matters
        .getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Corporate').getRecordTypeId();

    // Alternate approach, have a dedicated loop (and collection) to determine
    //   what records will be worked on
    Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsToWork = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity newOppValue : Trigger.newMap.values()) {
        // Less indentation is generally easier to read/reason about
        // Checking our skip condition and continuing allows us to keep the
        //   "real" work less indented
        if(newOppValue.RecordTypeId == excludedRecordTypeId) { 
            continue;
        }

        oppsToWork.put(newOppValue.Id, newOppValue());
    }

    // Since oppsToWork only contains stuff we know we want to work on, no
    //   additional logic is required in this loop
    for(Opportunity newOppValue : oppsToWork.values()) {
        if(Trigger.oldMap.get(newOppValue.Id).StageName != newOppValue.StageName &&
            newOppValue.StageName.equalsIgnoreCase('Closed Won')) {
            listOpptyIds.add(newOppValue.Id);
        }
    }
    
    if(!listOpptyIds.isEmpty()) {
        if(checkRecursive.runOnce()) {
            CreateCaseOnOptyCloseWonHandler.processOpportunities(listOpptyIds);
        }
    }


And of course, you should be looking into using a trigger framework so you can keep the logic outside of the triggers themselves. It may not matter much for simple/short triggers like this, but it can be immensely helpful as you add more things to your triggers (the additional isolation is especially nice for writing tests).

When i saw this many comments in the code, I felt it was some AI bot and then I saw your name :) Kudos to the efforts you put in to help newbies

Thank you so much @DerekF - I really appreciate your time to not only provide a solution, but to give a detailed explanation as well!
